# Microsoft Graph nextLink in SharePoint subsite lists

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

In SharePoint Online I have a sub site called "subsite_a" under my root site collection. This sub site has a generic list with about 50 items. When I query the top ten items:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/subsite_a:/lists/d383fe85-83e3-448d-afc8-cc42ee9de535/items?top=10
```

I get a @odata.nextLink property that looks like that:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('root')/microsoft.graph.getByPath/lists('d383fe85-83e3-448d-afc8-cc42ee9de535')/items",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/getByPath(path='pathValue')/lists/d383fe85-83e3-448d-afc8-cc42ee9de535/items?top=10&$skiptoken=UGFnZWQ9VFJVRSZwX0lEPTEw",
"value": [{ ... }]
}
```

When I use the nextLink I get an error *"The request is malformed or incorrect."*

For me the nextLink looks pretty malformed. I would expect to have the same api call with an additional skipToken.

Is the format of the nextLink correct ?

**Side note**: The nextLink looks and works correct when the list is directly under the root site

Answer (score 0):

I just added to the first URL GET query "skip" part from nextLink.
As a result nextLink should be like :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/subsite_a:/lists/d383fe85-83e3-448d-afc8-cc42ee9de535/items?top=10&$skiptoken=UGFnZWQ9VFJVRSZwX0lEPTEw
```